# Google Url shortner API not loging Short link history with API key

Tags: google-api, google-url-shortener

I am using the Goo.gl API to shorten some links.
The calls to the POST method are working good and the short URLs are working also, but I have a question regarding the short link history.

If I create a short url from the goo.gl page it will be stored there for me to see and see all the analytics associated to it, but if I generate it via the API POST using my API Key, the link will not be added to my history and I can't see any data related to it in the Goo.gl page. Is there anyway to access that information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the difference between public and private.

The [Url Shortener](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/) API is technically a public API.  Which means that you don't need to be Authenticated in order to use it.  This is why a public API key works.  However when you are using a public api key the api doesn't know who you are personally.

Solution: What you need to do is to switch to [Oauth2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2).   Authenticate your application get an access token and instead of sending the API key send the access_token.   Then when links are created they should be added to your account and you will get analytics for them.